# How can I make something happen when I buy a DevProduct (Roblox LUA)

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have made a major part of the code, but I am stuck in the important part. Here is what I'm doing:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local productID = 1218445231
local productInfo = MarketplaceService:GetProductInfo(productID, Enum.InfoType.Product)
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local function promptPurchase()
        local player = Players.LocalPlayer
        MarketplaceService:PromptProductPurchase(player, productID)
        purchased = true
    end
end)
if purchased == true then
 --stuck here (if you don't understand, the tsunami that I've made is supposed to become visible and start moving towards the map, however the part is in "Workspace". The button is in "StarterGUI". Please help.)
end
```

EDIT: Now updated the code, still don't know what to do. Do I get the workspace Service? If so, how do I code it that it sets the transparency of the tsunami to "0", and starts moving? This is my code:

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local player = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PurchaseEvent = ReplicatedStorage.PurchaseEvent
local productID = 1218445231

  
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    PurchaseEvent:FireServer(productID)
end)

if MarketplaceService:PlayerOwnsAsset(1218445231) then
    --Make tsunami become visible and start moving
end
```

Comment: What is the question? What is not working? Please add more information so we can help you.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a bit more code and context as to what the issue you are having is

Answer (score 1):

In the docs for [MarketplaceService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/MarketplaceService), there's a note

> the callback [ProcessReceipt](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/callback/MarketplaceService/ProcessReceipt) which must be well defined so that transactions do not fail.

After the purchase prompt is shown to the player, `ProcessReceipt` is called with the results of their choice. So that callback is how you make something happen after a user buys something.

A good structure for this kind of code is to have product purchases handled in a server Script, and to have UI elements communicate purchase intents using RemoteEvents. So do some setup :

- Create a RemoteEvent in ReplicatedStorage, name it something like "PurchaseEvent"
- Create a Script in ServerScriptService

Then update your LocalScript to look like this :

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PurchaseEvent = ReplicatedStorage.PurchaseEvent
local productID = 1218445231

-- listen for when players click the button to buy the product    
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    -- tell the server that we want this product
    PurchaseEvent:FireServer(productID)
end)
```

Then add this code to the server Script to handle the purchase :

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local PurchaseEvent = ReplicatedStorage.PurchaseEvent

-- listen for when players want to buy things :
PurchaseEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, productID)
    -- show the purchase prompt to the user
    MarketplaceService:PromptProductPurchase(player, productID)
end)

-- Define what should happen if a player buys something
-- NOTE - ADD FUNCTIONS FOR EACH SPECIFIC PRODUCT
local productHandlers = {}
productHandlers[1218445231] = function(player)
    print("TODO : spawn a tsunami")
end

-- Listen for when someone clicks on any of the buttons in the purchase prompt
MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(receiptInfo)
    -- Find the player who made the purchase in the server
    local player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)
    if not player then
        -- The player probably left the game, don't charge them yet
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end
    
    -- Look up handler function from 'productHandlers' table above
    local handler = productHandlers[receiptInfo.ProductId]
    if not handler then
        error(string.format("No handler is defined for %d", receiptInfo.ProductId))
    end


    -- Call the handler function and catch any errors
    local success, result = pcall(handler, player)
    if not success or not result then
        local message = table.concat({
           "Error occurred while processing a product purchase",
           " - ProductId: " .. tostring(receiptInfo.ProductId),
           " - Player: " .. player.Name,
        }, "\n")
        warn(message)
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end
 
    -- IMPORTANT: Tell Roblox that the game successfully handled the purchase
    return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
end
```

If you want to check if a user has bought something in the past and you don't want to charge them again, you can always check before you show the purchase prompt with the [MarketplaceService:PlayerOwnsAsset](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/MarketplaceService/PlayerOwnsAsset) function.